# ObservableList для чего

Tags: java, javafx

Поясните пожалуйста что из себя представляет в JavaFx список `ObservableList` и для чего он используется? Можно ли вместо обычных `ArrayList` использовать `ObservableList`?

Answer (score 5):

Интерфейс `ObservableList` помимо интерфейса `List` наследует ещё интерфейс `Observable`, в котором определены методы `addListener()` и `removeListener()` для того, чтобы можно было ловить события (для `ObservableList` это события  при изменении списка).

Comment: Спасибо. Стало более менее понятнее.

Answer (score -1):

Например при добавлении в checkBox значений, нужно передавать как аргумент ObservableList.

Comment: А зачем при добавлении в checkBox значений, нужно передавать как аргумент ObservableList?